# DDMS data drop down not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, ddms

I am running my application in HTC Sensation XE but i couldn't access the data->data files as i click the drop down nothing happens. I tried to reset the connection but it fails all the time don't know what the issue is can anyone help please. I have tried to find permissions but couldn't find it in my phone settings. 
Here is a screen shot of it

When i open File Explorer first:[image: Its when i open the file explorer first]

After clicking the data drop down button noting happens but the button disappears[image: No files are shown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are private files under /data/data. It is right that you can not see anything in it.

What your should do is to root your phone and remount your /data/data partition.

Comment: isn't there any other thing that i can do other than rooting my device?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have not set the permission to make your data accessible in your system.

You have to provide the permission to access the sdcard data from the settings then only you will be able to view and access the data->data folder.

Comment: how can i do that can you guide me please

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me,sorting it out in setting.